# Calculate volume over area

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem with calculating volume of given function over the area.

I enclose an image with my solution, however, I got a bad answer.

According to my book the answer should be pi when I got 2*pi.

Sorry for the quality, I couldn't get better with my phone. Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: +1 for "what you tried". Maybe writing it down in [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would have helped you to solve this on your own...

Comment: next time I'll do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong in:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r r(r\cos \phi +1)(r\sin\phi +1) d\phi dr=
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r (r^2\cos \phi +\color{red}r)(r\sin\phi +1) d\phi dr=\\
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r (r^3\sin\phi\cos \phi  +\color{red}r\sin\phi + r^2\cos \phi  +\color{red}r) d\phi dr=\\
\int_0^{2\pi}  \Biggr[ \frac14r^4\sin\phi\cos \phi  +\frac12\color{red}{r^2}\sin\phi + \frac13r^3\cos \phi  +\color{red}{\frac12 r^2}\Biggr]_0^1 d\phi =\\
\int_0^{2\pi}   \frac14\sin\phi\cos \phi  +\frac12\sin\phi + \frac13\cos \phi  +\color{red}{\frac12 } d\phi =
\dots=\pi
$$

Comment: Indeed, lost 20 minuts on that, thank you very much :)

Comment: your welcome...